# Difference between OR , AND with where in mysql

Tags: mysql, where-clause

i'm learning Mysql

but i felt confused after the examples below :

```
select * from `users` where username = 'admin' or true;
```

here it returned all the rows in users table !

(username = 'admin' or true ) should be true ? so where true

but in this example :

```
select * from `users` where username = 'admin' and true;
```

it returned one row (where username = 'admin')

but (username = 'admin' and true) should be true too !

so what's is the difference?

Comment: The condition is tested for each row. So if you don't have all users named "admin" you will only get one row returned...

Comment: Just replace with `1` with `true` and it should make more sense.

Comment: you mean for this example ? select * from `users` where username = 'admin' and 1;
it will check first it will check where usename = 'admin' ? because of AND ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
-- this is always true
WHERE 1 

-- this is only true for rows where the username is admin
WHERE username = 'admin'
```

Now check this [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table):

```
x  y | x and y | x or y
-----------------------
F  F |    F    |   F
F  T |    F    |   T
T  F |    F    |   T
T  T |    T    |   T
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

If you take

- `x` for `WHERE username = 'admin'` and
- `y` for `WHERE 1`

you should understand the results.

Comment: while using (or) it will execute 1=1 ( the logical expression first ? ) so it will be where true so all rows will be returned ,, but using (and) will execute both expression where username = 'admin' it will return  the row and true where this row = admin ! right ??

Comment: @user3771906 yes, DBMS use several optimizers to make database interactions fast. Check this for example: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html. The optimizer would erase the whole `WHERE` clause if it constantly evaluates to `true` like in `true OR (...)`.

Comment: using or if the is a logical expression true the whole where will be true so (where true) return all the rows ................ but in and the if we mix them username = 'admin' and true as you said the result will be the record :)

Comment: Thanks :) i was really confused :D

Comment: @user3771906 Well the same counts for `false || A` which will be trimmed to `A` as well as `true && A` to `A`. The boolean constants can help in cases you programatically create a `WHERE` clause, else you rarely need them. Some people find it easier to read `WHERE someBooleanValue = true` (compared to `WHERE someBooleanValue`)  though.

Answer (score 3):

you should read it differently.

the clause checks to see if username equals 'admin'.

read it as follows

```
(username = 'admin') and (1)
```

and for the or

```
(username = 'admin') or (1)
```

so the second will return all values in your db, because it checks if condition 1 or 2 is met. And condition 2 is always true.

```
WHERE 1
```

Comment: while using (or) it will execute 1=1 ( the logical expression first ? ) so it will be where true so all rows will be returned ,, but using (and) will execute both expression where username = 'admin' it will return the row and true where this row = admin ! right ??

Comment: yes, in the case of using and both clauses should return true and as you now know 1 always returns `true` so if the first clause `username = 'admin'` returns true, it will only return that record

Comment: but using or if the is a logical expression true the whole where will be true so (where true) return all the rows ................ but in and the if we mix them username = 'admin' and true as you said the result will be the record :)

Answer (score 1):

Mysql considers 1 as `true` so it is simple logic- `expression OR true` will always be true (so you get all rows) and `expression AND true` is equivalent to `expression`, so you get only the rowa that meets your condition

It looks a bit wierd, but mysql checks the expreesion (including the 1) fpr every row, even though 1 is not part of the table. It is still considered wheb decideling whether to select each row

Answer (score 1):

```
In a room there are 10 people.
1 is a woman, the rest are men.

How many in the room are People OR Women = 10. 
How many in the room are People AND Women = 1. 
How many in the room are People AND Men = 9. 
How many in the room are Men OR Women = 10. 
How many in the room are Men AND Women = 0.       
  In todays day and age, this is questionable ;)

Still I hope it helps
```

Comment: i understand that in case of logical expression but when i mixed logical expression with (where username = admin) made me confused ! :D